# Facing difficulty with applying inline navigator in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid for displaying data in tabular format.

I have tried to implement inline navigator in jqgrid but it taking me to this following error in firebug console:

> 'jqGrid - No such method: inlineNav' when calling method: 
>   [nsIDOMEventListener::handleEvent]

I have added following snippet for applying inline navigator in .js file:

```
   jQuery("#contactlist").jqGrid('navGrid','#contacttoolbar',{view:false,edit:false,add:false,del:false,search: false});
   jQuery("#contactlist").jqGrid('inlineNav',"#contacttoolbar");
```

so what do i do for applying this functionality??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be all you have to do, according to the [jqGrid inline edit docs](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing).

Are you sure that `inlineNav` is included in the version of jqGrid that you downloaded? What I mean is that, on the [download pag](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6)e you can choose which components to include in the grid. If `inlineNav` was left out, that would explain the error message. You should be able to verify this by opening up your minified jqGrid file and searching for the string `inlineNav`. If you do not find it, then you need to download jqGrid again with that component.

Otherwise, I suggest posting a larger code example so we can narrow down the problem.

Comment: thnk u mr.justin .....that was really helpful for me .....I need to redownload latest jqgrid plugin .....thank u again